# Select max amount rows

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Categorie
Rubriek
Adv_nr
```

For each rubriek it is possible that there are 100 or more adv_nr's.

I want to select max 5 rows from each rubriek, is this possible in one query?

Comment: Take a look at this article on [groupwise-limiting](http://blog.aharbick.com/2006/09/mysql-groupwise-limiting.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table as t1
where (select count(*) from table as t2
       where t1.rubriek = t2.rubriek and t2.adv_nr > t1.adv_nr) < 5
order by rubriek,adv_nr desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from *ad_table*  
    where category_id IN (   
         select *category_table*.id   
            from *category_table*, *group_table*
            where *category_table*.id = *group_table*.category_id)
    LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: yep, i'm trying to get data from 3 tables and assumed that the question was complete like this. But let me increase the question...
Table 1 contents groups, table 2 the categorys and table 3 the advertisements. I want to write a query that selects als the categorys from one group and for each category 5 advertisements...